# Get Expiry Date of .crt file in ios

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, certificate

I've few `.crt` file and `.provisionalprofile` and i need to display the expiry date.

tried to convert .crt to data and do encoding

```
func getExpiryDate() {
  guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample", withExtension: "crt"), let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
     return
   }
   data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>)->Void in
      if let dataPtr = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer<UInt8>(bytes), data.count) {
        print(dataPtr)
        if let plistData = String(data: dataPtr as Data, encoding: .isoLatin1) {
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what is not working. Do you get errors or warnings?

Comment: When we requesting for data we'll get nil so we are not able to get any meta data of crt file